# Forward port from docker bridge to local network?

Tags: networking, docker

I have a container running on Docker. I can access it via `172.17.0.1:8140` *(IP is the `docker0` bridge)*.

*`172.17.0.1` is available to my PC but none of the other devices on the local network.*

I want to make port `8140` *(on docker bridge)* available to my local network.

How can I forward a port from docker bridge so that it's available on my local network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to publish the port with the `-p` option in `docker run` or the `ports` section of docker-compose.yml. The format of the ports is an optional IP of the docker host (typically left blank), the port on the host, and the port of the container. If you don't provide a host port, a random port will be used. With the `docker run` command, this would look like:

```
docker run -p 8140:8140 ...
```

which will map, on all interfaces on the docker host, host port 8140 to container port 8140.

You should also ensure the iptables on the host permit connectivity to port 8140 on the host.

---

The docker-compose.yml syntax of the above looks like:

```
version: '2'
services:
  app:
    image: your_image
    ports:
    - "8140:8140"
```

Comment: I'm using the `ports` attribute on docker-compose currently. I'm guessing to do what you suggest with docker-compose, I should use `expose` instead of `ports`. Will give it a try.

Comment: `expose` will not publish the port for outside access, it only marks the port in a way other tools can use to lookup. You need to use `ports` to publish the port on your docker host.

Comment: I've had `- 8140:8140` set for `ports` in docker-compose from the start but `8140` doesn't seem to be available outside my host. Maybe I need to double check that I'm doing everything right.

Comment: Make sure you are connecting to the host IP, and that you do not have a firewall blocking the port.

Comment: I think I might be using the wrong IP, I will mark this correct if it ends up having been a mistake with that. Thanks.